# Unsure what is wrong with summarize() in my custom function

Tags: r, custom-function, tidyeval

I have a list of tables that I need to make using different variables, and I want to make a function that will let me make the tables differently each time by passing through different variables as arguments. There are many table outputs that need to be made, so I want to summarize the function I'm using to save on lines of code and general sanity (to my own insanity of learning function creation in tidyverse).

I am getting several different kinds of errors based on how I run the code, but the most consistent form I've run it is giving me:

```
Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `Number of
  vets with at least 11 patients =
  sum(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: site =
  "site1".
"Caused by error in `ifelse()`:
! unused arguments (condition = (~vars(var1)) >= 11, true = ~vars(var2), false = 0)"
```

Here's what I tried and what I was expecting to generate:

I have a dataset with many other variables but for example:

| site | var1 | var2 | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site1 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| site2 | 66 | 65 | 64 |
| site2 | 23 | 45 | 34 |
| site2 | 45 | 48 | 49 |
| site3 | 542 | 423 | 543 |
| site3 | 68 | 63 | 678 |

```
make_vet_site_table_row <- function(df, var1, var2) {
 df %>% dplyr::summarise(
                   "Total number of vets"                     = n(),
                   "Number of customers with at least 11 dogs" = sum(ifelse(condition = {{var1}}>=11, true = {{var2}}, false = 0)),
                   "Number of customers with at least 20 dogs" = sum(ifelse(condition = {{var1}}>=20, true = {{var2}}, false = 0)),
                   "Total number of dogs"                       = sum({{var1}}),
                   "Mean number of patients (by vet)"         = round(mean({{var1}}), digits = 2),
                   "Range of the number of patients (by vet)" = max({{var1}})- min({{var1}}),
                   "Smallest and largest number of dogs (by vet)" = paste0(min({{var1}}), ", ", max({{var1}}))
  )}

df.vetsite.2021 <- df.vetqm %>% filter(year=="2021" & var1_final_denom>0) %>% group_by(site)
```

#Here's what I want to be able to do from the function:

```
  df.vetsite1.2021 %>%  make_vet_site_table_row( var1 = vars(var1_final_denom), var2 = vars(var2_for_cnt))

  df.vetsite2.2021 %>%  make_vet_site_table_row( var1 = vars(var1_beginning_denom), var2 = vars(var2_for_cnt))
```

what I want is a table:

| site | Total number of clinicians | Number of clinicians with at least 11 patients | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site 1 | 81 | 54 | -------- |
| site 2 | 49 | 0 | -------- |
| site 3 | 49 | 0 | -------- |

Comment: What are you expecting the `ifelse` terms to do? base::ifelse does not have parameters called `condition`, `true`, or `false`. Do you mean, for example, `sum(ifelse({{var1}}>=11, {{var2}}, 0))`? Or `if_else` which is the dplyr variation that does have those parameters?

Comment: Where does "var1_final_denom" and "var2_for_cnt" come from?

Comment: @JonSpring yep! that fixes it. I assumed condition and true/false to exist in ifelse because I was using if_else before but switched out due to class issues. Thanks for your help!